# How can I specify custom global gitconfig path?

Tags: git, configuration

I'm in a bit of a bind with `Git`. I'm trying to execute `git commit` but I need to be able to swtich between `~/.gitconfig1` and `~/.gitconfig2` Is there a command line switch - or anyway to have `Git` use a different gitconfig file then the ones found at `/etc/gitconfig`, `~/.gitconfig` and `.git/config`?

Comment: Do you actually need two different configs while in one repo? Can you just use the .git/config for each repo to get what you want? I guess it's just not very elegant if you have only two common settings to spread across dozens of repos?

Comment: @Jefromi Yes I do. It's a unique situation that I have come across where two configs are needed

Comment: The other obvious alternative would be to globally alias `git commit-v2` (or something shorter) to `!export GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="Second name"; git commit`.

Comment: @Torek - More git goodness. These developers should be real proud of their inabilities....

Comment: Did you try `includeIf`, see https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I found a way to execute this - it wasn't elegant but it did work - and so far seems to be the only way to get this to work.

Git uses the `HOME` path to determine where `.gitconfig` is. I was able to perform something like this:

```
/home/marco/.silly/.gitconfig
/home/marco/.stupid/.gitconfig
/home/marco/.gitconfig
```

And when executing Git Commit (which is the only command that requires the `.gitconfig`) I override the home path.

```sh
HOME=/home/marco/.silly/ git commit -m "silly configuration"
```

You can then use alias to do this easily

```sh
alias sillygit="HOME=/home/marco/.silly/ git"
sillygit commit -m "silly stuff"
```

Comment: Nice hack. I can't seem to find any real way to do this - there's a GIT_CONFIG environment variable, but it only affects `git config` itself, in the same way as its `-f,--file` option.

Comment: For the git version 2.35.2 and above first user have to apply: `env HOME=/home/marco/.silly git config --global --add safe.directory <repo-path>`

Answer (score 3):

Mario Ceppi's [alias approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3595258) can be used in a slightly more elegant way using the `-c config=value` argument to `git`:

```
$ alias sillygit="git -c user.name=Silly -c user.email=silly@silly.org"
$ sillygit commit
```

This of course assumes you don't mind keeping the differing config keys in your `.bashrc` or the like instead of in your `.gitconfig`, and it has the caveat of breaking shell completion.

Answer (score 2):

[@amirouche's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3592351/how-can-i-specify-custom-global-gitconfig-path#comment126125292_3592351) and [Emil Lundberg's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46839351/5958465) can be combined to actually load another Git config file:

```bash
alias git="git -c 'include.path=/some/path/to/my/custom/.gitconfig'"
```

However, the user's `~/.gitconfig` file is still loaded. This approach only overwrites settings from the other git config files.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to use one `.gitconfig` file in each workspace, instead of having to switch between configs while working in one workspace, then `includeIf` may suffice, as it can be used to load custom configurations depending on workspace path elements or remote urls: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#_conditional_includes

Answer (score -3):

You can use --git-dir

```
git --git-dir /home/marco/silly/.git commit ...
```

Comment: --git-dir sets the repository being edited, which the questioner is specifically trying to avoid.