# How to _always_ force username/password prompt with "git commit"?

Tags: git, github

I wish to configure git config in such a way so that the command `git commit -m "some text"` will *always* prompt for the username AND password. Is this possible, and if so - how?

---

I'm on git 2.6.3 and I'm working with a private github repository which I clone onto my machine like this:

```
clone git https://github.com/user/private-repo.git
```

...and it will prompt me for my username and password.

I can then perform a `git add some_file` but when I execute `git commit -m "hello"` I get this:

```
*** Please tell me who you are

Run

git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
git config --globl user.name "Your name"

to set your account's default identity.
Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.

fatal: empty ident name (for <fredrik@devcentos6.(none)>) not allowed
```

I am aware of that you can use the `-c` option to define a user:

```
git -c "user.name=Your Name" -c "user.email=Your email" commit -m "hello"
```

**However, I would want to get a username/password prompt upon simply executing** `git commit -m "hello"`. Is it possible to configure git config in such a way?
I will be using different usernames for different commits.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Override configured user for a single git commit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19840921/override-configured-user-for-a-single-git-commit)

Comment: What username/password are you expecting git to prompt for? After all, you don't need to log into anything just to commit.

Answer (score -1):

> if you pass the --global option, because then Git will always use
>   that information for anything you do on that system. If you want to
>   override this with a different name or email address for specific
>   projects, you can run the command without the --global option when
>   you’re in that project.
>   [Source](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-First-Time-Git-Setup)

So it is possible to save identity for specific project. If I recall correctly configurations specific for repositories are stored in the repository `.git/config`.

Comment: Any comment what's wrong with my answer? I'd like to update it if possible ;)