# change default location of .gitconfig

Tags: git, windows-10, git-config

Running `git config --list --show-origin` on a Windows 10 machine shows me that the location of .gitconfig is in a remote location. I don't know how it ended there!

[image]

I tried few steps to change this from older posts. But with Git 2.30.00 I can't find some of the files or configuration that other StackOverflow Q/A mention.
I want to move this to somewhere locally, either D: or my user directory.

The `env` file that some mention from other questions is like this in my case

```
export PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"

# Allow SSH to ask via GUI if the terminal is not usable
test -n "$SSH_ASKPASS" || {
  case "$MSYSTEM" in
  MINGW64)
    export DISPLAY=needs-to-be-defined
    export SSH_ASKPASS=/mingw64/libexec/git-core/git-gui--askpass
    ;;
  MINGW32)
    export DISPLAY=needs-to-be-defined
    export SSH_ASKPASS=/mingw32/libexec/git-core/git-gui--askpass
    ;;
  esac
}
```

Comment: Does this question help, or are those solutions also failing for you? https://stackoverflow.com/q/28690019/3216427

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change your environment variable `$HOME`, in order to reference an existing local folder.

`set HOME=/local/path`

Git by default will use the `$HOME` environment variable to create the location of the global `.gitconfig` file.

There is also another way, without making changes to the `$HOME` variable, by creating an alias which overrides the `$HOME` variable. More information on this on the following webpage, [How can I specify custom global gitconfig path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3592351/how-can-i-specify-custom-global-gitconfig-path)

Comment: where do I find the actual $HOME path? what or who sets it initially? I tried this command in git bash but it didn't change anything. $HOME shows `bash: /y/: Is a directory`

Comment: Many programs use the `$HOME` variable. I would not change it just for Git, there might be unintended side effects.

Comment: And yet that answer got good scores here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/28690019/3216427 so maybe it's the way to go... ?

Comment: Backtracking some more, sorry: if Git is looking for `.gitconfig` in `Y://`, `$HOME` is probably not defined correctly, so this is probably the right solution.

Comment: this must be the solution to my issue. but found out that HOME was locked to Y: from the IT

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR** It might work best to tell Windows globally where you want your HOME

**Motivation**

While Shaqil's answer should work for you, I expect your strange `$HOME` variable might cause other problems. On Windows 10, I used to have my HOME set to a network drive when that network drive was visible at boot time, because of my administrator's Windows policies. This created issues not just with Git, but also with other programs that expect to find dot files in my home directory. It also caused a serious slow down of various programs because that network drive had a huge lag when working at home over the VPN.

**Solution**

My solution was more global: tell Windows that my HOME directory should be local. That fixed both Git and the lag for me, and several other things.

Go to

- Start Menu /

  - Settings /

    - Search for "variables" /

      - Pick "Edit environment variables for your account"

Then use either "Edit..." or "New..." to set

- `HOME` to `c:\Users\username`
- `HOMEDRIVE` to `C:`
- `HOMEPATH` to `\Users\username`

Although these may seem redundant, some programs rely on `HOME`, and others on `HOMEDRIVE` and `HOMEPATH`, to decide where your HOME is, so you should keep them consistent.

**Caveat**

Of course, this solution is only appropriate if you want all of your applications see see your home directory on the C: drive.

Comment: you are right. in my case that was also set from the IT guys. thank you for your detailed explanation.