# How to get VSCode to use different file location for the .gitconfig file

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I recently installed visual studio code onto my work computer and trying to set up my git repo's. I'm running into an issue where the VSCode wants to keep using my root directory (H://) to find the .gitconfig file.

I believe this is the case because VSCode installed into my system folder rather than the user folder. I don't have control on where VSCode is installed because my company admins determine that location.

Is it possible to make VSCode look into another folder path to find my .gitconfig file? I'm getting permission denied errors because the (H://) is a root drive.

My $HOME does point to my user profile folder on VSCode.

Comment: somewhat related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3592351/11107541

Comment: Is it read permission denied or write permission denied? If the latter, you could use `git config --local foo.bar baz`, in which `--local` is optional, to write the value into the local config file instead of the root config file.

Comment: @ElpieKay It's getting permissioned denied on writing to the folder. It errors out on reading the file because the file isn't in the H:// folder.